# How to search for twitter status with hashtag within user's time line

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using the library https://phpfashion.com/twitter-for-php

I am the user "`twiterUser1`" and I want to search within my timeline for status that contain the `#food`

if I tried in various plugins using `from:twiterUser1 #food` or `from:twiterUser1` I always get an empty result. I can only query on other's people timeline doing that.

How can I search within my own timeline for status that contain an specified hashtag? (I am happy to use a different/better library)